# Menu detached from panel on 49 inch monitor

Tags: monitor

I have a strange problem with my Kubuntu 19.10. The problem as the image shows is that the menu is detached from the rest of the panel on my Samsung 49" C49RG90 Curved WQHD HDR QLED 32:9 monitor. I wonder how to fix this problem.

One way is to change the resolution and then switch back to native resolution. That solves the problem but i don't think it should be like this in the first place.

[image: Menu detached from panel]